# MissingEndpoint: 'Endpoint' configuration is required for this service: queue name AWS ecs ec2

Tags: docker, go, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs

I'm Try to deploy my Golang Api-service, using ecs ec2 deployment.

but i'm getting error from this below function

```
sqsSvc.GetQueueUrl(&sqs.GetQueueUrlInput{
        QueueName: &queueName,
    })
```

so my service task is failed with below log as

**MissingEndpoint: 'Endpoint' configuration is required for this service:**

i have checked the aws configurations from env & those are correct.

**NOTE: I have successfully deployment this application normally using docker container in an ec2 instance manually, & that is successfully running.
I am try to do the same with ecs ec2 deployment.**

i have check over different solutions from internet, but nothing works.

also i have attached **AmazonSQSFullAccess** policy to my **ecsTaskExecutionRole** role as well as **ecsInstanceRole** role.

also i am able to send message by running the below cmd from this ecs ec2 instance, so my queue is accessible from everywhere.

`aws sqs send-message --region ap-south-1 --endpoint-url https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ --queue-url https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/account-id/my-sqs-queue/ --message-body "Hello from Amazon SQS."`

also **ping amazon.com** works from this ec2 ecs instance
Let me know, how can i debug & solve this issue.
using **github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.44.114**

Comment: See how you are setting the `--region` and `--endpoint` settings in the AWS CLI tool command you are running? Are you setting those same values on the `sqsSvc` in your Golang code? The error message indicates you are not. You should edit your question to show how you are initializing the `sqsSvc` in the code.

Comment: thanks did a quick check by printing env 
region was coming with double quotation. 
while others env were without quotation.